# Call of Duty: Black Ops zombies 'acsension' map won't fully load?

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops

I got Black Ops a few months ago from my uncle and it was in perfect condition. Since I played it and haven't taken it out of the Xbox 360 every map would work but, last night, I tried to play Acsension split screen and it loaded for about a minute and froze on the loading screen but the xbox itself didn't froze.

The disc now has a perfect ring along the edge. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the map pack and it still won't work. How can I fix this?

Also, I do not have Xbox live.

Comment: I tried to edit the question as best as I could, anyway, can you be a little more precise? What do you mean by the xbox didn't froze? Can you describe the "ring" on the edge of the disc?

Comment: Basically, this sounds like a problem with the disc, and can't be solved by re-installing the map pack. Try repairing the disc or get a new one

Comment: I'm with @Ben on this one.  It's a disc issue.  BO1 isn't too terribly expensive if you get it used.  I would try a new disk because I think yours is what's causing the problem.

Comment: @Ben - would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a physical mark on the disc, it's likely going to be an issue with the disc itself, not any of the software. I had a similar issue with one of my games (COD:WaW as a matter of fact), that always had issues loading extra content, like DLC, sometimes even updates, or would simply crash with a "damaged disc" error.

I would recommend replacing the disc, or repairing it. Often video stores have disc polishing machines that you can pay to use, which may solve your issue, depending on the severity of the damage. If not, replacing the disc may be your only option.